# Issue with generating Serenity reports with Appium and Jbehave

Tags: maven, appium, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am new to Serenity and JBehave and I am facing issues in generating reports with Serenity. Please find below my POM.xml file.

I am getting blank reports and results.csv file also doesn't show any information about the ran tests, however, we are getting results in Jbehave's report.

```
4.0.0
SmokeTest
SmokeTest
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

<properties>
    <serenity.version>1.2.2</serenity.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.25-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-junit-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-jbehave</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>/ONE20SmokeTest/src/test/java/*/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.15</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi @halfer i am sorry about that. I am getting blank reports and results.csv file also doesn't show any information about the ran tests, however, we are getting results in jbehave's report. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with the Surefire/Failsafe configuration, and no tests are actually being run: see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html and http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: Hi John, does Serenity work for native Android and IOS apps as well. If yes, can you please share a sample serenity.properties file for a native app automation?

Comment: Yes, Serenity will work with anything that Appium can work with.